# how basic_string<char>,which only offered a template parameter "char", works while basic_string is a there-parameter template

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I define a string object like this:

```
string test;
```

I want to know how stl implement string,and I found that string is basic_string,like this:

```
typedef basic_string<char>    string;
```

but basic_string is a template like this:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
class basic_string
{
  typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_CharT>::other _CharT_alloc_type;

  // Types:
public:
  typedef _Traits                       traits_type;
  typedef typename _Traits::char_type           value_type;
  typedef _Alloc                        allocator_type;
  typedef typename _CharT_alloc_type::size_type     size_type;
  typedef typename _CharT_alloc_type::difference_type   difference_type;
  typedef typename _CharT_alloc_type::reference     reference;
  typedef typename _CharT_alloc_type::const_reference   const_reference;
  typedef typename _CharT_alloc_type::pointer       pointer;
  typedef typename _CharT_alloc_type::const_pointer     const_pointer;
  typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, basic_string>  iterator;
  typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const_pointer, basic_string>
                                                        const_iterator;
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator>           reverse_iterator;
  ......
}
```

I just want to kown that how basic_string,which offered only one template parameter "char",works while basic_string is literally a there-parameter template

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::basic_string` has default template arguments. According to the standard, the declaration is:

```
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
  class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string
```

Comment: I just rechecked the source code of basic_string in /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h which you can see:
`template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    class basic_string`

Comment: @Brian,thank you so much,It's declared in /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stringfwd.h